# Is there any DateTime ObservableValue in Java like StringProperty or how can I make one?

Tags: java

I want a DateTime ObservableValue so I can add Listener to listen to change in System Date.

Comment: Please make your question understandable. Add your code also that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own ObservableValue:

```
private ObjectProperty<DateTime> cal = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "cal", DateTime.now());
```

The above example uses [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), but with Java 8 you can also use [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html).

Comment: But how do I make that property listen to my System date change?

Comment: should I run a thread to periodically check and update the value of cal?

Comment: This is some personal advice: Don't. Use a timer that will update your `cal` object periodically. Thereby you can implement different game speed and make the whole thing testable. Basically using a timer could be considered being a listener on the system time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.